# How to disable SSL for chef-manage?

Tags: ssl, chef-infra, unicorn

## TL:DR;

How does one disable SSL for the chef-manage addon of a chef-server?

---

## Purpose

I'm working on a Vagrant setup which builds (among others) a chef server and chef node. The purpose is for an educational workshop (an introductory venture into using Chef server for enterprise applications). For this purpose, SSL on chef-server / chef-manage is an unnecessary complication and I'm looking to keep the curriculum lean and free of pitfalls.

## chef-server

I've successfully disabled ssl on my chef-server via `nginx['enable_non_ssl'] = true` within the `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` file. Attempting `curl http://chef.server.url/` returns the expected html content (rather than a redirect).

## chef-manage

After adding chef-manage to chef-server (via `chef-server-ctl install chef-manage && chef-server-ctl reconfigure && chef-manage-ctl reconfigure`), attempting `curl http://chef.server.url/` returns a 302 redirect. This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405996/disable-ssl-on-chef-server) to a different but related question seems to say that:

- the chef-server webui is run via nginx
- the chef-manage webui is run via unicorn
- unicorn contains `config.force_ssl=true unless ENV['NO_SSL']` (Found in `/opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config/environments/production.rb`).
- Performing `export NO_SSL=true` on the chef server and reconfiguring will disable ssl for chef-manage.

I've attempted this but a `curl http://chef.server.url/` still returns a 302 redirect.

How can I disable ssl for the chef-manage webui?

Any tips, hints, or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an intro workshop I wouldn't use Manage at all. It's just one more thing to learn for basically no benefit, and it's not quite deprecated but definitely in a similar orbit (Automate is where any major new development is going).